# Initialize certain size to an array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Hi i'm trying to create an array with a prefixed size(eg,size of 10) in the Main and then add items(eg, 3 items) in the array, this will make the array have 7 unused spaces, later on, I want to write a method that trim the unused size.

But How can i first create an array with a fixed size because obviously my constructor won't allow this operation below.

```
*Bag<String> names = new Bag<String>(**10**);*


public class Bag<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Iterable<T> {
  private int MAX_ITEMS = 10; // initial array size
  private int size;
  private T[] data;

  public Bag( ) {
      data = (T []) new Comparable[MAX_ITEMS];
      size = 0;
      }

  public static void main(String[ ] args) {
      Bag<String> names = new Bag<String>();
        names.add("Seattle");
        names.add("Chicago");
        names.add("New York");

        System.out.println(names.size());
        for (String name : names)
            System.out.println(name);

        names.trimToSize();
        System.out.println(names.size());
  }
}
```

Comment: It is not obvious to me that this is not allowed. My Compiler (Java8, Eclipse) accepts this.

Comment: @CoronA Because my bag constructor don't take any parameters

Comment: Where is your `iterator()` method. This code will noy compile.

Comment: @akhil_mittal its there, I will show it now

Comment: @Robert: You want to create a fixed size array, so you won't need a parameter. Your program does not only compile (if one adds the missing method stubs), it also creates an array of size 10. Yet I do not understand the hint `*Bag<String> names = new Bag<String>(**10**);*`.

Comment: @CoronA oh sorry please ignore the first line. yes, thats the problem, the new array i have created in the main is not size 10, it initialized at 0, and after adding 3 items, it's of size 3.

Comment: @Robert: It is not. print the size in the constructor. Maybe you want to point out that the bag has size 0 and gets to 3, but that is perfectly intuitive.

Comment: @akhil_mittal: Do you really thinkt that the Iterator implementation helps this discussion?

Comment: @CoronA im sorry, im still very new to Java, i dont understand, is there a difference between the array size and bag size?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77273/discussion-between-robert-and-corona).

Comment: It wont but it will make the code compile. Don't you think the code posted must at least compile?

Comment: @akhil_mittal Hi, The code did compile, i had the Iterator with me, i didnt show it here thats all

Comment: @akhil_mittal: It would be fine if the code compiles. But actually adding an iterator does not achieve this, there are several missing methods and all of them are not subject of this problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can create the following method in a Utility class and use it every time you need it:

```
public static <T> T[] newArrayOf(T[] t, int len){
        return (T[]) Array.newInstance(t.getClass().getComponentType(), len);
    }
```